# Why do I need knot insertion to compute a single BSpline basis element?

Tags: scipy, spline

I just wanted to obtain a single B-Spline element. I used the BSpile.basis_element() function in scipy. However, I stumbled upon the following:

From the doc of basis_element() it reads that the given knot-sequence is extended with
k artificial knots to the left and to the right (in the example below k=1 and we have -1 and 3 added to the given knot sequence.)

```
from scipy.interpolate import BSpline

b = BSpline.basis_element([0, 1, 2], extrapolate=False)
b.t
#array([-1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
```

Now: I have access to the knots via the t attribute. However, here is my question: Why do I need this knot extension in the first place. In my understanding the value of the B-Spline basis element does not depend on the choice of the added knots (that is, it would be the same if we extended it with -9000 instead of -1). That it, the basis_element should be computable directly from [0,1,2]. I do not understand the knot-insertion - Nor do I understand what I am suppossed to do with the t attribute if it does not provide me with any further information.